# Creating default object from empty value in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm just trying to do my update function in Laravel 5.3 and then I got the following error:

> "ErrorException in gestionpersonnel.php line 96: Creating default
>   object from empty value"

And this is the code for the function:

```
$id = $request->input('id');
$personnel = personnels::find($id);
$personnel->CIN = $request->input('CIN ', 8);
$personnel->nom  = $request->input('nom', 50);
$personnel->prenom = $request->input('prenom', 50);
$personnel->date = $request->input('date');
$personnel->numtel = $request->input('numtel');
$personnel->adress = $request->input('adress');
$personnel->emai = $request->input('email');
$personnel->post = $request->input('post');

$personnel->save();

return redirect('/home')
```

And line number 96 is:  `$personnel->CIN = $request->input('CIN ', 8);`

Comment: Dump the `$personnel` and check the result if it is empty you are not getting the value.

Comment: Most likely there is no personnel with your given $id. Use findOrFail() or another method to check whether your model exists